# Facebook javascript sdk fb.login not redirecting

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm using this to get permissions from the user.This is get permission but not redirecting.I get a blank page.

```
  FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.session) {
   if (response.scope) {
    document.location.href='xxx.php';
} else {
  // user is logged in, but did not grant any permissions

    } else {
  }
  }, {scope:'read_stream,publish_stream'});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works good for me:

```
FB.login(
 function(response){
  if(response.authResponse){
    //perms granted
    window.top.location.href = 'xxx.php';
  }else{
    //perms NOT granted
  }
 }, {scope:'read_stream,publish_stream'}
);
```

Comment: P:It is showing login popup,if i click login ,it is executing else part and it has to show the permission pop up next right

Comment: @user1051322 I use this code within a function which is called from an "onclick". Does the Firebug console show any error?

Comment: P:If i click on page tab,i'm getting else part.

Comment: @user1051322 This code should actually work fine if the user is already logged into the app. Looks like my solutions is not what you need :(